# Please help Veracode issuing CWE 15 External Control of System or Configuration Setting n file name

Tags: vb.net, webforms, veracode

Veracode is issuing a CWE 15 error:

> Description: This call to system_data_dll.System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection.!newinit_0_1() allows external control of >system settings. The argument to the function is constructed using untrusted input, which can disrupt service or cause an >application to behave in unexpected ways. The first argument to !newinit_0_1() contains tainted data. The tainted data >originated from earlier calls to system_web_dll.System.Web.HttpRequest.get_Files, >system_data_dll.System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar, and system_web_dll.System.Web.HttpContext.get_User.
>
> Remediation: Never allow untrusted or otherwise untrusted data to control system-level settings. Always validate untrusted .input to ensure that it conforms to the expected format, using centralized data validation routines when possible.

I am allowing web users to upload a file through an IHttpHandler in vb.net (webforms) that is temporarily stored while the file is being processed.  In order to keep the filename unique, I am appending the context.user.identity.name to the front end of the file. I'm not sure how this would be considered untrusted input or how it could be modified.

Users of this system are limited to a 6-char ID that must start with an alpha char and the other 5 are alpha-numeric.  I have a regex scrubber on the field before it is prepended to the local file name.  I am also checking that the user is authenticated.

I'm more than concerned if this is a trust issue over an authenticated user id.  Obviously, I could choose some other manner to prepend a variable in front of the file (but it would make it harder to trace files is something blows up).

```
dim wkId as string = "xxxxxx"
if context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated then
    wkId = ScrubWkId(context.User.Identity.Name)
end if
For i = 0 To context.Request.Files.Count - 1
        controlName = context.Request.Form("controlName" & Trim(Str(i)))
        sFile = context.Request.Files.Get(i)
        If SharedCode.Common.Utilities.MimeTypeIsAllowed(sFile.FileName) Then
            Select Case action
                Case "dataload" 'only expect a single file on a dataload
                    'sFile = context.Request.Files.Get(i)
                    a = InStrRev(sFile.FileName.ToString, "\")
                    b = wkId & Right(sFile.FileName.ToString, sFile.FileName.ToString.Length - a)

                    Dim wkFile As String = GetFileUploadPath(context) & MakeValidFileName(b)
                    sFile.SaveAs(wkFile)
```

Answer (score 0):

After many scans, I determined that Veracode does not like any part of the upload file name - no matter what scrubbing functions you attempt to use.  Here is a short function that builds a unique file name with extension (note: checking the value of the extension against a white list is not the same as setting a new variable value based on the value of the extension in Veracode world).

```
Public Shared Function generateTempFile(ByVal sfileName As String) As String

    Dim wkFilePrepend As String = "d" & DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss") & "_" & Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
    Select Case Path.GetExtension(sfileName).ToUpper
        Case ".XLS"
            wkFilePrepend = wkFilePrepend & ".xls"
        Case ".XLSX"
            wkFilePrepend = wkFilePrepend & ".xlsx"
        Case ".TXT"
            wkFilePrepend = wkFilePrepend & ".txt"
        Case ".CSV"
            wkFilePrepend = wkFilePrepend & ".csv"

    End Select
    Return wkFilePrepend
End Function
```